# How to Reset the PMU on a PowerBook G4 15" A1095 5, 4 laptop?

Tags: battery, charging, power-management, powerpc

I have been refurbishing 3 PowerBook G4 15" A1095s and 1 PowerBook G4 15" A1106 and need help with battery issues.  All of them have been able to charge a battery.  I have attempted to and rebuilt 1 A1078 battery with excellent results and have failed on another.   I have learned how to reset the Pram but do not know how to reset the PMU or if that will even make a difference.   Also I am wondering if removing the Pram battery has an effect on the charging system as I have one time experienced the single flashing green light on an A1078 battery and managed to get it to charge by  putting it in a G4 A1095 that I had just reassembled and had previously removed the pram battery.  I need to know this because the A1078 battery rebuild I failed on will not charge on 2 machines that will charge other batteries.  I have an A1148 battery that I rebuilt that has never charged beyond 88% and now has dropped to 66%.  I assume that I either used some bad cells or damaged the controller within the battery.  Any useful information will help.

Answer (score 1):

The PMU reset key sequence for this model differed to earlier ones.

There are two ways to reset the Power Management Unit on this model (1) using a key sequence and (2) using the PMU Reset pads.

**Key Sequence**

Use the following procedure:

1. If the PowerBook is on, turn it off.
2. Disconnect the power adapter
3. Remove the main battery.
4. Hold the power button down for ﬁve seconds, then release.
5. Install the main battery and connect the power adapter.
6. Press the power button to restart the PowerBook.

**PMU RESET pads on logic board**

This model has pads for PMU RESET, which work when their pads are shorted together (with a tool like a ﬂat blade screwdriver). The pads are separated with a white horizontal line between the pads.

The pads are located near the edge of the logic board, just above center of the hard drive.

See photo below:

[image]

<sup>**Source:** PowerBook G4 (15-inch 1.67/1.5GHz)  Service Source © 2005 Apple Computer, Inc. All rights reserved.</sup>